# How to correct this error in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have customized part of function `feature_select.m` below to use my own generated masks `whole_brain_mask_1`,`whole_brain_mask_2`,…,`whole_brain_mask_10` into `subj`.

```
function [subj] = feature_select(subj,data_patin,regsname,selsgroup,varargin)

% No-peeking feature selection
%
% [SUBJ] = FEATURE_SELECT(SUBJ,DATA_PATIN,REGSNAME,SELSGROUP,...)
%
% Calls a statmap generation function multiple times, using
% a different selector each time. This creates a group of
% statmaps, which are then thresholded to create a group of
% boolean masks, ready for use in no-peeking
% cross-validation classification.
%
% Adds the following objects:
% - pattern group of statmaps called NEW_MAP_PATNAME
% - mask group based on the statmaps called
%   sprintf('%s%i',NEW_MASKSTEM,THRESH)
%
% DATA_PATIN should be the name of the pattern object that
% contains voxel (or other feature) values that you want to
% create a mask of. If DATA_PATIN is a group_name, then this
% will use a different member of the group for each
% iteration.
%
% REGSNAME should be a binary nConds x nTimepoints 1-of-n matrix
%
% SELSGROUP should be the name of a selectors group, such as
% created by create_xvalid_indices
%
% For each iteration: call the ANOVA on the DATA_PATIN data,
% which will produce a statmap, employing only the TRs
% labelled with a 1 in the selector for that iteration
%
% NEW_MAP_PATNAME (optional, default = DATA_PATIN +
% STRIPPED_NAME). The name of the new statmap pattern group
% to be created. By default, this will be 'anova' if
% STATMAP_FUNCT = 'statmap_anova' etc.
%
% NEW_MASKSTEM (optional, default = DATA_PATIN +
% 'anovathresh'). The name of the new thresholded boolean
% mask group to be created from the ANOVA statmap. You'll
% need to create multiple mask groups if you want to try out
% multiple thresholds, so adding the threshold to the name
% is a good idea
%
% THRESH (optional, default = 0.05). Voxels that don't meet
% this criterion value don't get included in the boolean
% mask that gets created from the ANOVA statmap. If THRESH =
% [], the thresholding doesn't get run
%
% STATMAP_FUNCT (optional, default = 'statmap_anova'). Feed
% in a function name and this will create a function handle
% to that and use it to create the statmaps instead of
% statmap_anova
%
% STATMAP_ARG (optional, default = []). If you're using an
% alternative voxel selection method, you can feed it a
% single argument through this
%
% Need to implement a THRESH_TYPE argument (for p vs F
% values), which would also set the toggle differently xxx
%
% e.g. subj = feature_select( ...
%         subj,'epi_z','conds','runs_nmo_xvalid','thresh',0.001)

% License:
%=====================================================================
%
% This is part of the Princeton MVPA toolbox, released under
% the GPL. See http://www.csbmb.princeton.edu/mvpa for more
% information.
% 
% The Princeton MVPA toolbox is available free and
% unsupported to those who might find it useful. We do not
% take any responsibility whatsoever for any problems that
% you have related to the use of the MVPA toolbox.
%
% ======================================================================


defaults.new_map_patname = '';
defaults.new_maskstem = sprintf('%s_thresh',data_patin);
defaults.thresh = 0.05;
defaults.statmap_funct = 'statmap_anova';
defaults.statmap_arg = struct([]);
args = propval(varargin,defaults);

if isempty(args.new_map_patname)
  % get the name of the function being run, e.g. 'statmap_anova' -> 'anova'
  stripped_name = strrep(args.statmap_funct,'statmap_','');
  args.new_map_patname = sprintf('%s_%s',data_patin,stripped_name);
end

% append the thresh to the end of the name
args.new_maskstem = sprintf( ...
    '%s%s',args.new_maskstem,num2str(args.thresh));

% Find the selectors within the specified group
selnames = find_group(subj,'selector',selsgroup);
nIterations = length(selnames);

[data_patnames isgroup] = find_group_single(subj,'pattern',data_patin,'repmat_times',nIterations);

if length(data_patnames) ~= length(selnames)
  error('Different number of patterns and selectors');
end

if nIterations == 0
  error('No selectors in %s group',selsgroup);
end

% % this warning used to be here to remind people of the
% % existence of peek_feature_select, but since there are good
% % reasons why one might want to have just one selector
% % without using peek_feature_select, i took it out
% if nIterations == 1
%   warning('You''re only calling the anova once because you have one selector - use peek_feature_select instead?');
% end

if ~ischar(args.statmap_funct)
  error('The statmap function name has to be a string');
end

disp( sprintf('Starting %i %s iterations',nIterations,args.statmap_funct) );

for n=1:nIterations
  fprintf('  %i',n);

  % Get the pattern for this iteration
  cur_data_patname = data_patnames{n};

  % Get the selector name for this iteration
  cur_selname = selnames{n};

  % Name the new statmap pattern and thresholded mask that will be created
  cur_maskname = sprintf('%s_%i',args.new_maskstem,n);
  cur_map_patname = sprintf('%s_%i',args.new_map_patname,n);

  % if a pattern with the same name already exists, it
  % will trigger an error later in init_object, but we
  % want to catch it here to save running the entire
  % statmap first
  if exist_object(subj,'pattern',cur_map_patname)
    error('A pattern called %s already exists',cur_map_patname);
  end

  if ~isempty(args.statmap_arg) && ~isstruct(args.statmap_arg)
    warning('Statmap_arg is supposed to be a struct');
  end

  % Add the current iteration number to the extra_arg, just in case
  % it's useful
  args.statmap_arg(1).cur_iteration = n;

  % Create a handle for the statmap function handle and then run it
  % to generate the statmaps
  statmap_fh = str2func(args.statmap_funct);
  subj = statmap_fh(subj,cur_data_patname,regsname,cur_selname,cur_map_patname,args.statmap_arg);
  subj = set_objfield(subj,'pattern',cur_map_patname,'group_name',args.new_map_patname);

  if ~isempty(args.thresh)
    % Now, create a new thresholded binary mask from the p-values
    % statmap pattern returned by the anova
    subj = create_thresh_mask(subj,cur_map_patname,cur_maskname,args.thresh);
    subj = set_objfield(subj,'mask',cur_maskname,'group_name',args.new_maskstem);
  end

end % i nIterations

disp(' ');
disp( sprintf('Pattern statmap group ''%s'' and mask group ''%s'' created by feature_select', ...
          args.new_map_patname,args.new_maskstem) );
```

**This is the piece of the function above that I have adapted to use my own masks:**

```
dirIn_Mask = ['/D disk/my_fold/My_generated_Mask'];

data_patin = subj.patterns{1,2}.name;  

defaults.new_maskstem = sprintf(‘whole_brain_mask’); 

defaults.statmap_arg = struct([]);

args = propval(varargin,defaults);

args.new_maskstem = sprintf( '%s',args.new_maskstem );

for n = 1:1:10

fprintf('  %i', n );

inputFile_mask = ['whole_brain_mask_',num2str(n)];

load(fullfile(dirIn_Mask,inputFile_mask)); 

    cur_maskname = sprintf('%s_%i',args.new_maskstem,n );

    subj.masks{1,(runID+1)}.mat = whole_brain_new_1; 


    subj = set_objfield(subj,'mask',cur_maskname,'group_name',new_maskstem);
end
```

**And this is the error I'm getting:**

```
Attempt to execute SCRIPT varargin as a function:
C:\D disk\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\matlab\lang\varargin.m
Error in MVPA (line 89)
args = propval(varargin,defaults);
```

Can anyone help me fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `varargin` as an argument of `propval`, but `varargin` is not defined anywhere in your code. In that case, `varargin` rolls back to Matlab script `varargin`. As a result, the interpreter assumes you want to run it as a function that returns values to `propval` and given that scripts are not supposed to return values, you get the error message.

Just as a side note: `varargin` is usually set as the last argument of a function to allow programmers to declare functions with variable number of arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am trying to figure out a way to fix it. If you know how to fix it , please let me know!

Comment: What is `propval` expecting as input? Why is `varargin` not defined in MVPA and you are still passing it as an argument to `propval`?

Comment: I just want to use part of the function to write my generated mask to "subj".

Comment: Take out the `propval` and `defaults ...` lines and include `args.new_maskstem = sprintf(‘whole_brain_mask’);` 
`args.statmap_arg = struct([]);`
`args.new_maskstem = sprintf( '%s',args.new_maskstem );`

Comment: I am trying immediately.

Comment: now the error looks like this: Reference to non-existent field 'name'.

Error in get_number (line 58)
  if strcmp(objcell{p}.name,objname)

Error in get_object (line 42)
objno = get_number(subj,objtype,objname);

Error in set_objfield (line 67)
obj = get_object(subj,objtype,objname);

Error in Classification_01_02_by_using_MVPA (line 105)
    subj =
    set_objfield(subj,'mask',cur_maskname,'group_name',args.new_maskstem);

Comment: I am now pasting the "set_objfield.m" function to the original question, Please take a look at it! Thank you so much

Comment: I think you should remove this function from the question. What appears to be going on now is that your adapted code is not including lines that may be adding other fields to `subj` such as `name`. These lines **appear** to be: statmap_fh = str2func(args.statmap_funct);`
`subj = statmap_fh(subj,cur_data_patname,regsname,cur_selname,cur_map_patname,args.statmap_arg);`
  `subj = set_objfield(subj,'pattern',cur_map_patname,'group_name',args.new_map_patname);`

Comment: Another thing: you should read the guidelines on how to ask questions in SO. We are not supposed to go on debugging your code, but rather to provide insights to the original questions you post. Your original question boiled down to a problem of using `varargin` improperly, something that @rayryeng and I spotted and for which we suggested corrections.

Comment: I will remove this fucntion.

Comment: I just simply want to add my generated mask as a field to subj, I do not need other fields, Is there any way to modify my code to achieve my purpose. I finish the feature selection part by using my own code, not using this "feature_selection.m". Now I just want to simple add my generated mask as a field of subj by using the way that "feature_selection.m" did, so I can call the mask later.

Comment: Well, you would have to find out what are the fields of `subj` object and set one by one manually, including adding your mask. Make sure you set all fields that are necessary for when object `subj` is used. `subj = statmap_fh(subj,cur_data_patname,regsname,cur_selname,cur_map_patname,args.statmap_arg);` seems to be initializing the fields, maybe you can modify it to include only the stuff necessary, and would eventually be able to skip the call to `set_objfield`.

Comment: I am trying immediately.

Comment: the problem is I do not need statmap_fh, since I use my own way to generate statistic map and I just want to put my generated mask into it. I do not know how to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `varargin` from your code.  `varargin` is a special keyword that is only available when you run the code as a function.  `varargin` allows for a variable number of inputs to be placed into your function.  These inputs are hashed into a cell array.

Because this is a script file, that variable does not exist.  This is also apparent from the MATLAB error you received.  FWIW, MATLAB error messages are very verbose.  It would be hard to misinterpret or misunderstand what they're trying to say.

Therefore, do this:

```
args = propval(defaults);
```

If that doesn't work, then I'm not sure how `propval` takes in inputs, but perhaps fool it with putting in an empty cell array:

```
args = propval(cell(1,1), defaults);
```

Because the function `propval` relies on a variable number of inputs, it should handle the case where `varargin` doesn't exist, and so we can simulate `varargin` having no additional parameters by using an empty cell array.

Comment: I am trying immediately.

Comment: when I do "args = propval(defaults)", the error is Error using propval (line 112)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in Classification (line 89)
args = propval(defaults);;

Comment: when I do "args = propval(cell(1,1), defaults)", the error is:Error using propval (line 109)
Property-value pairs must be a cell array or a structure.

Error in Classification (line 89)
args = propval(cell(1,1),defaults);

Comment: I don't know how that function looks like so I can't help you any further. Sorry! Good luck!

Comment: if I do not use use Propval , how to modify my code to achieve my purpose?